# Как одним двойным щелчком мыши выделить все составное слово, разделенное дефисами

Tags: adobe-brackets

Как в adobe-brackets одним двойным щелчком мыши выделять **такие-составные-слова**?
В sublimetext это делается настройкой вот такого параметра:

```
// Characters that are considered to separate words
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

Есть ли такая возможность в adobe-brackets?